# QGIS 3.x Metadata

Tags: qgis, metadata

I tried the new Metadata-Editor (layer-props) in QGIS 3.0.x and in my case QGIS did not save the metadata with apply/save (tried SHP, GPKG layers) and closing the dialog - only when using "Metadata" - "Save...".

Is this behaviour normal (I think yes) - it is a bit confusing that the metadata does not get saved when using "Apply/Close" (maybe a warning would help)?

Depending on the different file-types (SHP, GPKG/SQLite, PostGIS) it looks like the metadata is always saved to a *.qmd in the project-dir and not in the databases (in case of SQLite/GPKG/PostGIS)?

Is it possible to save the metadata within the databases?

Answer (score 4):

The [QGis user guide](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=metadata#metadata-properties) says that metadata is saved inside the project. So you have to create a QGis project and save it in order to keep your metadata.

I found that, when working with shapefiles, if you save the metadata to an external file with the same name as you shape, it gets read automatically. But could not figure out how to do this for geopackages.